# Immediate-alerts Email Notification not sending emails when new user is added

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

we have recently set up SharePoint 2010 farm environment and i have configured outgoing email settings in central admin to valid SMTP server and to and from email addresses as well.

1. Now the problem is every time we add new users to sites and select the send welcome email option it is not sending any mails.
2. I have tried all the steps mentioned in this blog 
   [enter link description here](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/02/sharepoint-alerts-not-working-troubleshooting-checklist.html#ixzz2aSvOz3hB)

   3.I have checked log files as well i don't see any errors and I have gone through Immediate alerts timer job it is also showing succeeded .
3. Still I am not able to resolve this issue.

Did any one faced this issue. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you said adding new user, is it new to site collection or new to farm? after how many days / hour it start working if it is?

Comment: new user in the sense he is already in AD we when we add some one to site level, sub-site we send an welcome email to users which is not working. It is not at all working